# How do I use the DevExpress DropDownButton c#?

Tags: c#, devexpress, logic

I am trying to create a dropdown so that users can see the names of accounts. How do i do that using DevExpress DropDown Button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should associate the drop-down button with a popup control/context menu. To accomplish this task use the [DropDownControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsDropDownButton_DropDownControltopic) property.

```
DXPopupMenu menu = new DXPopupMenu();
menu.Items.Add(new DXMenuItem("Admin"));
menu.Items.Add(new DXMenuItem("Guest"));
// ... add more items
dropDownButton1.DropDownControl = menu;
// subscribe item.Click event
foreach(DXMenuItem item in menu.Items) 
    item.Click += item_Click;
// setup initial selection
dropDownButton1.Text = menu.Items[0].Caption;
//...

void item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // synchronize selection
    dropDownButton1.Text = ((DXMenuItem)sender).Caption;
    // ... do something specific
}
```

The following objects can be used as popup controls:

- [PopupMenu](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsPopupMenutopic) - represents a popup menu managed by a [BarManager](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsBarManagertopic) or [RibbonControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControltopic) component.
- [PopupControlContainer](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsPopupControlContainertopic) - represents a container for other controls. This control is also managed by a BarManager component.
- [DXPopupMenu](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressUtilsMenuDXPopupMenutopic) - represents a popup menu.

Comment: That was a great response, but why is that I have to click the button and NOT the little arrow now to see the options in the drop down? @DmitryG

Comment: dropDownButton1.Text = ((DXEditMenuItem)sender).Caption; throws an exception when i try to change the value. @DmitryG

Comment: @James: about your first comment - if you are using the DropDown button together with PopupMenu you can use button click event to proceed the selected action. So, the button Click's handling depends on your exact task only.

Comment: @James about the second comment - My example is demonstrated only the idea of menu items usage. So, you are free to modify it as you needed. But if you've changed the code, ensure that all the logic are changed accordingly. E.g. in your case, make sure that the exact sender is the DXEditMenuItem...

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you. Just wondering, is there a book where you learned this? So I can continue reading about this topic? That would help a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Oh ok, Thank you. Just wondering, is there a book where you learned this? So I can continue reading about this topic? That would help a lot. Thank you @dmitryG

Comment: @James Not quite sure about the book you mentioned, but all things related to DevExpress you can find in [online documentaion](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument7874) or in [DevExpress Support Center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)